# How to set title of rendered anchor tags for <asp:BulletedList DisplayMode="HyperLink"/>

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a bulleted list in ASP.NET whose DisplayMode is set to HyperLink. When the control is rendered, the links display perfectly fine but additionally I want to set title for each anchor tag. How do I do this?

aspx file:

```
<asp:BulletedList ID="BL1" runat="server" DisplayMode="HyperLink" DataTextField="AnchorText" DataValueField="URL" />
```

Code Behind File: 
In the code behind file I am data binding the `BL1` with a list.

`List<UrlData> listOfUrls`.

where UrlData class has three public properties

```
class UrlData
{
     public string URL {get; set;}
     public string AnchorText {get; set;}
     public string TitleText {get; set;}

    //public UrlData to initialise properties
}
```

Comment: Please share how you are populating `BulletedList `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:-

**Option 1:**

Loop through the items inside your BulletedList and add the `title` attribute like this:-

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   foreach (ListItem item in BL1.Items)
   {
       item.Attributes["title"] = GetToolTip(item.Value);
   }
}
```

Obviously you will have to call the datasource again to get the respective tool-tip:-

```
private string GetToolTip(string url)
{
    return UrlDataList().First(x => x.URL == url).TitleText;
}
```

Assuming, `UrlDataList()` will return `List<UrlData>` which you are binding to `BL1`. Obviously this is not the best way since we are querying the data twice.

**Option 2:**

You can instead create the same behaviour using a repeater control (recommended way):-

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptDemo" runat="server">
   <HeaderTemplate>
      <ul>
   </HeaderTemplate>
   <ItemTemplate>
      <li>
        <%# String.Format("<a href=\"{0}\" title=\"{1}\">{2}</a>",Eval("ID"),Eval("Salary"),Eval("Country")) %>
      </li>
   </ItemTemplate>
   <FooterTemplate>
      </ul>
   </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Simply Bind it like this:-

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (!Page.IsPostBack)
   {
      rptDemo.DataSource = UrlDataList();
      rptDemo.DataBind();
   }
}
```

Comment: @ihimv - Did you get a chance to look at my answer?

Answer (score 1):

You should use a repeater:

Bind the data source:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

      rprUrls.DataSource = listOfUrls;
      rprUrls.DataBind();

}
```

Your repeater will look like:

```
<asp:Repeater ID = "rprUrls"  runat="server">
        <HeaderTemplate><ul></HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <li><%# string.Format("<a href=\"{0}\" title=\"{2}\">{1}</a>", Eval("URL").ToString(), Eval("AnchorText").ToString(), Eval("TitleText").ToString()) %></li>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate></ul></FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```